# Mysql login via CLI on Linux with complicated password

Tags: mysql, linux

So I trying to login to mysql on Gentoo with the following syntax

```
mysql --user=myUsername --password=passWord
```

However, my password is something like this

```
2k*`pI5G=BT86/5\"[]DBdTCo
```

I am wondering what characters I should escape in order to login.

Thanks.

Comment: i hope to Gad that is not your real password

Comment: Don't provide the password in the clear, it gets saved in your history as well (which you can clear). Just do `mysql -u username -p` and it will prompt. You can paste the password in at this point.

Comment: Still doesn't work. And NO, it's not my password but some alteration from it. Haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No clue why but it works this way.

```
touch myfile.txt

inside [myfile.txt]
    [mysqld]
    user=the username
    password=the password
```

and voila, `mysql --defaults-extra-file=myfile.txt` works like a charm ... Don't know why it doesn't work with stdin as others have suggested though ...

Answer (score 1):

typically mysql login looks like

`mysql -u user -p`

when you hit enter, mysql will ask you for the password.  You shouldn't have to escape any characters.

Comment: its more likely that you have the username wrong, or access is restricted to certain machines.  You don't have to escape password characters from the command line.

Comment: When writing the password to stdin, nothing has to be escaped (unless it's out of normal character range or something).  Are you sure that your password is correct?

Comment: Yes. Since the database writing process from the App to the DB is still working correctly, I believe the PW im trying to use is the right one.

Comment: heh, are you typing in the *encrypted* password, not the plaintext password?

Comment: Nah, it's a plaintext password ... Nothing is encrypted right now :(

Answer (score 0):

I would refrain from typing it on the command line (for security reasons too), and instead either just use "--password" and get prompted for a password or use an additional my.ini where you set the default password (and that only your user has read access to).

If you really want to type it on the command line, you'll need to escape any bash special characters (should be google-able).